# Changes to be made here such that program work for longer inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

My objective is to take two inputs 1 string and an integer which is always a multiple of length of string, and print the output divided in integer parts but each part should not have repetition.
Eg.
Input:

```
AABCDDDFAHIJ
3
```

Output:

```
ABC     in AABC, A is repeated twice hence removed
DF     D is repeated thrice in DDDF hence repeated ones are removed 
AHIJ    nothing is repeated.
```

This code somehow works for smaller values few times but is obviously still wrong.

```
s,i=input(),int(input())
ln=int(len(s)/i)
lis=[]
k=0
for j in range(0,len(s),ln):
    temp=[]
    temp=s[j:j+ln]
    lis.append(temp)
s_=[]
for m in lis:
    seen=[]
    for j in m: 
        if j not in seen:
            seen.append(j)
    t=''
    for m in seen:
        t+=m
    s_.append(t)
for j in s_:
    print(j)
```

Comment: Why is this "obviously still wrong"?  The code looks like it should work, but I have no idea what sort of problem I'm supposed to be looking for.

Comment: Just from the description, why is the first output not `AB` rather than `ABC` given that the first chunk of length 3 to process is `AAB`?

Comment: @JonSG I think 3 is the number of chunks, not the chunk length.

Comment: Why is `seen` a list? Make it a string and then you don't need the extra `for m in seen:` loop.

Comment: You can also use `t = "".join(seen)`

Comment: 3 is number of parts in which the string should be divided (number of chunks)

Comment: @johanlenon Why do you think your code is wrong? Post an example of incorrect results.

Comment: There's no need for `temp=[]` since you reassign the variable on the next line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.